# parsing a phrasal verb

Tags: grammar

Got a small question.

Consider a phrasal verb within a sentence, such as : make up.

As in : She made up her mind.

Would you consider :

1. up as a preposition, and so, *her mind* is an **object of preposition**.
2. up as an adverb and so, *her mind* is a **direct object** ?

Would you say that when considering phrasal verbs in general, their particles are in fact complements of the verb ?

Much obliged.

Comment: This is actually a good conceptual question. I think it would make more sense to treat the particle as object of preposition, rather than as adverb modifying verb. _She ran into her friend_, for example, conveys the idea of _her **position** vis-a-vis her friend (the cardinal function of prepositions), rather than the **act** of running itself (thus, ruling out the possibility of adverbs.)